# Make a table from ul elements without the top and the sides borders in CSS

Tags: css, image, text, html-lists, tabular

value 1  || value 2
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
value 1 ||  value 2
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
value 1 ||  value 2
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

I have a `ul` tag inside them there are `li` tags with a text and an image. I want them to look like the table above. Inside each block there will be the image and the text next to each other. The table will be without borders from the top & left & right ((the `||` and `^` are for the line of the table))

```
<ul>
   <li>value 1</li>
   <li>value 2</li>
   <li>value 3</li>
   <li>value 4</li>
   <li>value 5</li>
   <li>value 6</li>
</ul>
```

Inside each `li` tags there will be:

```
<li>
   <img src="test.jpg"/>
   <p>some text</p>
</li>
```

Comment: Why don't you use a `<table>` instead?

Answer (score 0):

Nesting another set of `ul`s into each `li`.

**[Working JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/jsve/vLn2f/1/)**

```
<ul class="top-level">
    <li class="border-bottom">
        <ul class="horizontal">
            <li class="border-right">
                <p>some text</p>
            </li>
            <li>
                <p>some text</p>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="border-bottom">
        <ul class="horizontal">
            <li class="border-right">
                <p>some text</p>
            </li>
            <li>
                <p>some text</p>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="border-bottom">
        <ul class="horizontal">
            <li class="border-right">
                <p>some text</p>
            </li>
            <li>
                <p>some text</p>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
 </ul>
```

And then use this CSS:

```
.horizontal li {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-right: 5px;
}

.top-level {
    list-style-type: none;
}

.border-right {
    border-right: 1px solid black;
}

.border-bottom {
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```

You can modify the borders with whatever styles you want.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a **[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UFV4t/1/)** with 6 list items made of `img+p` (with an **empty `alt`** on each image please), with an `.even` class on half of them (`:nth-child(2n)` is compatible with IE9+ and I still support I8 but if you don't support the latter, you don't need that class).

That will work if each image is taller than its text, otherwise you'd have to use a bunch of paragraphs (not in a list) in order to recreate CSS table layout with "rows" containing 2 paragraphs and a paragraph being a "cell" (I mean displayed as `display: table-cell`)

```
* { -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
}

ul {
    width: auto;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
li {
    list-style-type: none;
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px;
}
li > img {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 1em;
}
li > p {
    overflow: hidden;
}
.even {
    border-left: 1px solid #333;
}
li {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #333;
}
```